# Duplicate registration in symfony when rabbitMq is killed

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I am saving the database by consuming the data in rabbitmq, I am using symfony framework.
I have a question like this.
After the data was sent from RabbitMQ to the application, the rabbitMQ server was killed. Here, since the data is still in pedding mode, it is added back to the queue, but since the data is sent to the application, the database is recorded. When the RabbitMQ server is up, the same data goes back to the application and is recorded again. How to get rid of duplicate process

Answer (score 0):

This is what [Consumer Acknowledgements](https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/confirms) are for.

> When a node delivers a message to a consumer, it has to decide whether the message should be considered handled (or at least received) by the consumer.
>
> [...]
>
> Depending on the acknowledgement mode used, RabbitMQ can consider a message to be successfully delivered either immediately after it is sent out (written to a TCP socket) or when an explicit ("manual") client acknowledgement is received.

It's up to you at what point in the application you want to consider the message "processed" - it could be as soon as the application receives it, or after it has been fully saved to the database.

If you're worried that the acknowledgement itself could fail, you could combine with a database transaction:

1. Receive message from RabbitMQ, in manual ack mode
2. Start transaction (and put the following in a catch block which rolls it back on error)
3. Insert into DB
4. Send basic.ack to RabbitMQ
5. Commit transaction

That way, if something goes wrong at step 3 or at step 4, the message is pending in RabbitMQ, and the database doesn't have the data.